# Is there a security risk to serve Django admin page on regular http rather than Https?

Tags: python, django

I just finished my first experience with Django on real application and we are running it on apache2.

Since I am newbie I am wondering if it is right to have admin page served on http?

Is https a better solution? how much of risk will I be experiencing by not having it run on https?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can better understand this from here [django security](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/security/)

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you have a login mask in a browser and transfer user credentials from browser to webserver it is **highly recommended** to use https, because otherwise the credentials can easily be read by others.

This applies to everything, not just django admin.